# sendkeys types wrong character sometimes

Tags: c#

rare but on occasion sendkeys will type the wrong character

sent: BLAH1a

typed: BLAH!a

sent: +^%][~)(

typed: +^%][~0(

```
Thread.Sleep(250);
SendKeys.SendWait(temp);
SendKeys.Flush();
```

What other methods could I use to type keys to another process? I need to also send function keys, key modifiers (alt,shift,ctrl) and also support unicode

Comment: Is this from a WinForms application?

Comment: it is not a .net app that I will sending the keys to

Comment: is your caps key on?

Answer (score 0):

```
# You could use user32.dll for example:
# referenced: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/virtual-key-codes

namespace Typer
{

using System;
using System.Threading;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            KeyboardManager.PressKey(KeyboardManager.VK_LWIN);
            KeyboardManager.PressKey(KeyboardManager.VK_R);
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            KeyboardManager.ReleaseKey(KeyboardManager.VK_LWIN);
            KeyboardManager.ReleaseKey(KeyboardManager.VK_R);

            KeyboardManager.PressAndReleaseKey(KeyboardManager.VK_P);
            KeyboardManager.PressAndReleaseKey(KeyboardManager.VK_O);
            KeyboardManager.PressAndReleaseKey(KeyboardManager.VK_W);
            KeyboardManager.PressAndReleaseKey(KeyboardManager.VK_E);
            KeyboardManager.PressAndReleaseKey(KeyboardManager.VK_R);
            KeyboardManager.PressAndReleaseKey(KeyboardManager.VK_S);
            KeyboardManager.PressAndReleaseKey(KeyboardManager.VK_H);
            KeyboardManager.PressAndReleaseKey(KeyboardManager.VK_E);
            KeyboardManager.PressAndReleaseKey(KeyboardManager.VK_L);
            KeyboardManager.PressAndReleaseKey(KeyboardManager.VK_L);

            KeyboardManager.PressAndReleaseKey(KeyboardManager.VK_RETURN);
            Thread.Sleep(10000);

            KeyboardManager.PressAndReleaseKey(KeyboardManager.VK_N);
            KeyboardManager.PressAndReleaseKey(KeyboardManager.VK_O);
            KeyboardManager.PressAndReleaseKey(KeyboardManager.VK_T);
            KeyboardManager.PressAndReleaseKey(KeyboardManager.VK_E);
            KeyboardManager.PressAndReleaseKey(KeyboardManager.VK_P);
            KeyboardManager.PressAndReleaseKey(KeyboardManager.VK_A);
            KeyboardManager.PressAndReleaseKey(KeyboardManager.VK_D);
            KeyboardManager.PressAndReleaseKey(KeyboardManager.VK_RETURN);
            Thread.Sleep(4000);

            KeyboardManager.PressAndReleaseKey(KeyboardManager.VK_RETURN);



            KeyboardManager.SayWhatIsAwesome();
        }
    }
}




    namespace Typer
    {
        using System;
        using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

        public class KeyboardManager
        {
            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, uint dwExtraInfo);

            public KeyboardManager() { }

            public const int VK_LWIN = 0x5B; // Left Windows Key

            public const int VK_RETURN = 0x0D; // Enter
            public const int VK_SPACE = 0x20; // Space
            public const int VK_A = 0x41; // A key
            public const int VK_B = 0x42; // B key
            public const int VK_C = 0x43; // C key
            public const int VK_D = 0x44; // D key
            public const int VK_E = 0x45; // E key
            public const int VK_F = 0x46; // F key
            public const int VK_G = 0x47; // G key
            public const int VK_H = 0x48; // H key
            public const int VK_I = 0x49; // I key
            public const int VK_J = 0x4A; // J key
            public const int VK_K = 0x4B; // K key
            public const int VK_L = 0x4C; // L key
            public const int VK_M = 0x4D; // M key
            public const int VK_N = 0x4E; // N key
            public const int VK_O = 0x4F; // O key
            public const int VK_P = 0x50; // P key
            public const int VK_Q = 0x51; // Q key
            public const int VK_R = 0x52; // R key
            public const int VK_S = 0x53; // S key
            public const int VK_T = 0x54; // T key
            public const int VK_U = 0x55; // U key
            public const int VK_V = 0x56; // V key
            public const int VK_W = 0x57; // W key
            public const int VK_X = 0x58; // X key
            public const int VK_Y = 0x59; // Y key
            public const int VK_Z = 0x5A; // Z key


            public const int VK_UP = 0x26; // up key
            public const int VK_DOWN = 0x28; // down key
            public const int VK_LEFT = 0x25; // left key
            public const int VK_RIGHT = 0x27; // right key

            public const uint KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x0002;
            public const uint KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x0001;

            public static void SayWhatIsAwesome()
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
                {
                    PressAndReleaseKey(VK_S);
                    PressAndReleaseKey(VK_T);
                    PressAndReleaseKey(VK_A);
                    PressAndReleaseKey(VK_C);            
                    PressAndReleaseKey(VK_K);

                    PressAndReleaseKey(VK_SPACE);

                    PressAndReleaseKey(VK_O);
                    PressAndReleaseKey(VK_V);
                    PressAndReleaseKey(VK_E);
                    PressAndReleaseKey(VK_R);
                    PressAndReleaseKey(VK_F);
                    PressAndReleaseKey(VK_L);
                    PressAndReleaseKey(VK_O);
                    PressAndReleaseKey(VK_W);

                    PressAndReleaseKey(VK_SPACE);

                    PressAndReleaseKey(VK_I);
                    PressAndReleaseKey(VK_S);

                    PressAndReleaseKey(VK_SPACE);

                    PressAndReleaseKey(VK_A);
                    PressAndReleaseKey(VK_W);
                    PressAndReleaseKey(VK_E);
                    PressAndReleaseKey(VK_S);
                    PressAndReleaseKey(VK_O);
                    PressAndReleaseKey(VK_M);
                    PressAndReleaseKey(VK_E);

                    PressAndReleaseKey(VK_RETURN);
                }
            }

            public static void PressAndReleaseKey(int key)
            {
                PressKey(key);
                ReleaseKey(key);
            }

            public static void PressKey(int key)
            {
                keybd_event((byte)key, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | 0, 0);
            }

            public static void ReleaseKey(int key)
            {
                keybd_event((byte)key, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What about modifier keys like ALT, SHIFT, CTTL?